# Next.js: getserversideprops without SSR

Tags: next.js

I am looking for an elegant way of redirecting users to a login page when they are not authenticated. I have implemented it in the following two ways:

1. Try loading the data client side and redirecting if the API returns that the user is not authenticated.
2. Use `getServerSideProps` to redirect via the server when the user is not logged in.

I prefer option 2, but I am uncertain whether this would result in the page (if the user is not redirected) to be rendered server side. As our server is not the most powerful, I would like the dynamic data to be rendered user side (using `swr` for example) and the static elements (such as the footer) to be statically generated.
I tried wrapping my head around whether or not `getServerSideProps` does this, but as far as I understand, it will render the static elements server side on each request.

So I am trying to figure out how to use `getServerSideProps` (or something similar) so that I can:

- Redirect users server side
- Build static elements at build time (not at each request)
- Fetch and render dynamic data client side

I think I got a bit lost in how Next.js works, so would love to know more!

**EDIT**

Perhaps would it be possible to extend the default GET handler for a page to insert some authentication middleware? I know I can add middleware in `getServerSideProps`, but then I would be doing server side rendering.

Comment: You can't use `getServerSideProps` and have the page statically generated at build time at the same time. Either you server-side render the page on each request and do the redirect on the server, or statically generate the page at built time and do the redirect on the client.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, that is what I suspected. But the question is, is there a way (not necessarily with `getServerSideProps`) to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: @BramVanbilsen Have you considered using a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) that handles this for you? A caveat here is that this disables automatic static optimization, so you'll have to manually tell Next.js to static build a page by using `getStaticProps`.

Comment: @brc-dd Considered it! But, would love to just keep working with what next.js gave us. But 100% yes, if I don't end up finding a solution, I think a custom server is my only option. Thanks for the suggestion!